# Getting mismatched BEGIN and END error. but each BEGIN has an END and vice versa

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have checked and cant seem to find a mismatch in either BEGINs and ENDs as well as BEGIN TRANSACTIONs and COMMITs. Is there something I am not understanding about RETURNs or Since I am calling multiple Stored Procedures within a Stored Procedure is this causing nested Transaction and that is the cause of the error?

I'm designing a back-end that allows a application store and track the movements of slots like draft picks between departments within an organization. I have a stored procedure for when you create a new department, you supply it how many slots you want this new department to have and it generates the slots in the Slot table then adds them to the DepartmentSlots table linking them to the department that was just created.

```
-- ================================================================================
-- Add Department
-- ================================================================================
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddDepartment       
        @DepartmentName                 VARCHAR(50),
        @AllocatedSlots                 DECIMAL(18, 2) 

    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            -- See if the department Exists
            DECLARE @DepartmentExists       AS BIT = (SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT @DepartmentName FROM [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Departments WHERE UPPER(DepartmentName) = UPPER(@DepartmentName)) THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) END)
            IF (@DepartmentExists = 0)
                BEGIN

                    INSERT INTO [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Departments(DepartmentName, AllocatedSlots)
                    VALUES(@DepartmentName, @AllocatedSlots);

                    DECLARE @DepartmentID AS INTEGER = (SELECT MAX(DepartmentID) FROM Departments)

                    -- Now that we have created a department with newly allocated slots, we have to create those records in DepartmentSlots, and Slots
                    EXECUTE uspGenerateSlots @DepartmentID, @AllocatedSlots;
                END
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT 'DEPARTMENT EXISTS'
                END
        COMMIT;
GO


-- ================================================================================
-- Add Slots
-- ================================================================================
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddSlot

    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            -- Incriment the Identity Column adding a new slot
            INSERT INTO [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Slots DEFAULT VALUES;
            -- Return the SlotID
            RETURN(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(SlotID),1) FROM [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].Slots);
        COMMIT;
GO


-- ================================================================================
-- Add Department Slots
-- ================================================================================
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspAddDepartmentSlots
        @departmentID       INTEGER,
        @SlotID             INTEGER
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            -- We are Assigning a Slot to a Department but we aren't Assigning any one to it
            INSERT INTO [HeadCount_Ver01].[dbo].DepartmentSlots
            VALUES (@departmentID, @SlotID, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        COMMIT;
GO


-- ================================================================================
-- Generate Slots
-- ================================================================================
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE uspGenerateSlots
        @departmentID       INTEGER,
        @allocatedSlots     INTEGER
    AS
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SET XACT_ABORT ON;

        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            DECLARE @i      INTEGER = 0;
            DECLARE @SlotID INTEGER = 0;
            WHILE @i < @allocatedSlots
                BEGIN
                    EXECUTE @SlotID = uspAddSlot;
                    EXECUTE uspAddDepartmentSlots @departmentID, @SlotID;
                    SET @i += 1;
                END
        COMMIT;
GO
```

It runs exactly as expected except for the error "Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements" which when the calling application tries to execute this stored procedure causes an exception.

Comment: `BEGIN TRANSACTION` / `COMMIT` do not form syntactic blocks, and any indentation is purely cosmetic. The error message is only telling you that, at the end of everything, `@@TRANCOUNT` is still positive, meaning there were not as many `COMMIT`s as there were transactions started in the batch. This is a direct result of `uspAddSlot` issuing a `RETURN` before it issues a `COMMIT` -- the `COMMIT` is never reached. In general, you should not use `RETURN` at all for anything that's not an error code; use an output parameter. (And you probably want `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` or a `SEQUENCE` to get IDs.)

Comment: All of your SP's start and end transactions, but some of them call another SP (such as `uspAddDepartment` which calls `uspGenerateSlots`). Nested tranasctions don't exist in SQL Server so `uspGenerateSlots` will `COMMIT` both tranasctions and then when the `COMMIT` in `uspAddDepartment` is reached, you have a `COMMIT` for no related transaction.

Comment: Nice spot there too @JeroenMostert . Seems there's a few issues going on. To add to your point, if you do need to "return" a value, use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: True nested transactions don't exist in SQL Server, but it will fake them by incrementing the open transaction count for every `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and decrementing it for every `COMMIT`, so it is not the case that the first `COMMIT` commits everything. In fact, only the last `COMMIT` does. (Savepoints can be used for "partial commits", *sort of*, but that's another kettle of fish.)